# Kerberos: accessing host by IP address

Tags: java, authentication, httpclient, kerberos

I know that Kerberos does not work with IP adresses, it relies on domain names and correct DNS entries only.

But I found that old versions of overthere library allows to use IP address with Kerberos authentication.

I extracted code from overthere and created small java project that demonstrates that https://github.com/igolikov/KerberosWithIP

It uses Apache HttpClient to send WSMan request to hyper-v host.

I also found that it works with httpclient 4.3.3 and it doesn't work with httpclient 4.4.1

How it is possible that it works with IP?

UPD1. I suppose that httpclient or something in sun.security may use revers DNS lookup. I tried to intercept traffic with Wireshark, and found 1 Revers DNS lookup (in-addr.arpa), but it responded with "No such host" because default DNS server cannot do revers DNS for this IP.

UPD2. Here is server configuration
There are SPNs for host name and for IP address

```
SPN( 1 )   =       WSMAN/10.10.64.60 1+=1
SPN( 1 )   =       HOST/somehost.corp.org.com 1+=1
SPN( 1 )   =       HOST/somehost 1+=1
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to ask. How it is possible that it works with IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kerberos can work without DNS just fine, the problem DNS solves is both sides of the connection agreeing on the same service principal to use. If I use the kerberos API to fix that principal to standard one, then as long as the server side has that prinicpal in it's keytab it will continue to work.

I.E. you have to know the kerberos principal that the service you are connecting to uses before you can connnect. Most service principals are of the form

```
service/dns.name.of.host
```

But the service principal can be anything as long as the client software knows what to use "somehow".